# QuickDialog QEntryElement ellipsis and overlapping issue

Tags: ios, ipad, quickdialog

I am using `QEntryElement` from QuickDialog library. For some reason title of `QEntryElement` have ellipsis when seeing in iPad.How should I fix this.

[image: iPad Portrait]

Another issue is in Landscape mode in iPad text typed in overlaps with title of `QEntryElement`.
[image: iPad Landscape]

```
 let userNameElement: QEntryElement = QEntryElement(key: "ACCOUNT")
    userNameElement.title = "Account"
    userNameElement.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress
    userNameElement.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None
    userNameElement.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
```

Comment: Same problem ... and I cannto find way to fix in code eather... looks like there is soem layout constraints aplyed in TableViewCell for cell element and then sizes dont work wich tries QTableViewCell to aply... Did you solve it somehow ? Some workaround ? I have pretty much code based on this lib...

Comment: No solution so far :(

Comment: Ah I have one already... but I forgot what I did ;) have to find it...

Comment: Can you find it and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

So for ellipsis problem I did this...

I checked out QuickDialog so I have it locally and
modified QTableViewCell like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviewsInsideBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
   ...
   self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y,
            self.textLabel.frame.size.width, self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
}
```

I know its not nice solution but it looks better ...

[image]

and when I comment that added line I get back this :
[image]